# How to connect 2 machines through QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qt5, qtcpsocket

I have a program (client) that needs to connect to another machine (server).

The problem is, I don't know what IP I should connect to and what port I should foward. This goes both to the server and to the client.

Let's say I am using port `1234`for testing purposes.

In my server, i have the following code:

---

MyServer.cpp

```
QString MyServer::StartServer()
{
QHostAddress ipAddress;
QList<QHostAddress> ipAddressList = QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();
for(int i=0;i<ipAddressList.size();i++)
{
    if(ipAddressList.at(i) != QHostAddress::LocalHost &&
       ipAddressList.at(i).toIPv4Address())
    {
        ipAddress = ipAddressList.at(i);
        break;
    }
}
if(ipAddressList.isEmpty())
    ipAddress = QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost);
if(listen(ipAddress,1234))
{
    qDebug() << this->serverAddress().toString();
    qDebug() << this->serverPort();
    return QString("Server online!");
}
else
    return QString("Error!");
}
```

---

In the tests I made, the IP will always be my internal IP (192.168.25.208). However, in my client program, i never know what IP to connect.

this is my client code:

---

MyClient.cpp

```
void Pesquisa::ConnectConfig()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(Connected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(Disconnected()));
    //What IP should I use here?
    socket->connectToHost("192.168.25.208",1234);
}
```

---

Should I connect to my internal IP the server is running? the external IP of the machine (server)? Also, if I need to use my extenal IP.... it is dynamic, so thats a problem.

Comment: I think I "found a way"! I will use "no-IP" and try to use the host name from it in the software. Maybe it will work. I will come back with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### THE MAIN PROBLEM

The connection with my local machines worked because I passed as parameter my "internal IP". And that is also why it didn't worked with other machines. So changing it to the "external IP" and making the server listen to all IPv4 (as said by Mattia F.) would make outside connections.

Like this:

**Client:**

`socket->connectToHost("177.157.4.38",1234)`

**Server:**

`if(listen(QHostAddress::anyIPv4,1234))`

Once that was discovered, than it became easy right? not really. As I live in Brazil, here we can't have static IP without paying a "little" extra.

### MY SOLUTION

I downloaded the free software from "No-IP" called "DUC", which gives you a hostname for your dynamic IP and checks for changes every 5 minutes. By connectiong to this hostname, I managed to establish connections with my server from anywhere.

This was my final line for the client:

**Client:**

`socket->connectToHost("andsegcar.ddns.net",1234)`

"andsegcar.ddns.net" is my hostname created by "No-IP".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the code itself.

If you want to test your programs, running both the server and the client on you machine, make the server listen to all addresses (but I don't know why you don't allow localhost in your server code) and your client connect to localhost (127.0.0.1).

To make the server listen to all addresses, I use:

```
server->listen (QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 1234);
```

Anyway if you want to connect to the server from another machine, you have to use the external IP of the server PC of course.

But to do that, you need a static IP. Usually you can ask your Internet Provider for a static one.

Comment: I am 100% certain that running both in the same machine works (just tested). Now doing it from diferent machines.... thats not working at all (Maybe because I am using the internal IP... which makes no sense now that I think about it).

Comment: Let's say that I live somewhere that if I want a static IP.... i will have to pay for it. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Well i can't help you now. I got mine for free, and i doubt you can do anything else than paying.